# Prove if $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable set, there exists a continuous function $f$ differing from $\chi_{E}$ on a set of measure $< \epsilon$?

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure, characteristic-functions

I am reviewing my analysis notes, and I don't really understand the proof given by my professor.  He first proved if $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable set and $\epsilon > 0$, then there is an open set $O$ such that $m(O) - m(E) < \epsilon$, which makes perfect sense.  Then, using that fact, he proved that, given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ a continuous function $f$ such that $m (\{ x \mid f(x) \neq \chi_{E}(x) \} ) < \epsilon$.  Anyone know how to construct the function $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an open set and define

$$O_n := \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}; d(x,\mathbb{R} \backslash O) \geq \frac{1}{n} \right\}.$$

It is not difficult to show that $O_n$ is closed and $O_n \uparrow O$. Now choose $n$ sufficiently large such that $m(O \backslash O_n)<\varepsilon$. It is not difficult to show that there exists a continuous functions $f_n$ such that $0 \leq f_n \leq 1$ and

$$f_n|_{O_n}=1 \qquad \qquad f_n|_{\mathbb{R} \backslash O} = 0;$$

this follows from Urysohn's Lemma. In particular, $$m(\{x; f(x) \neq 1_{O}(x)\})< \varepsilon.$$ Using that $m(O \backslash E)<\varepsilon$, the claim follows.

Comment: Why is $f_{n}$ continuous?  What is $f$?  Is it the limit of the $f_{n}$'s?

Comment: @user46944 No, for each $n$ there exists a continuous functions $f_n$ such that $f_n|_{O_n}=1$ and $f_n|_{\mathbb{R} \backslash O}=0$. Now $f=f_n$ for some (fixed) $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: So, if it is not difficult to show that there exists a continuous function $f_{n}$ for each $n$, can you show it?  I realize this must be some obvious fact, but I don't see it.  If we are drawing pictures, do you just mean you connect 0 and 1 "continuously" on $O \setminus O_{n}$?

Comment: @user46944 Basically that's the idea, yes. More precisely, $$f_n(x) := \frac{d(x,\mathbb{R} \backslash O)}{d(x,\mathbb{R} \backslash O)+d(x,O_n)}$$ does the job.

Comment: @saz Note: it is not true that $m(O \backslash O_n)<\varepsilon$ for large enough $n$, as that measure could be always infinite.  The result can be salvaged by considering $G_m = O\cap(m,m+1)$ for each integer $m$ and taking a closed subset $F_m$ of that with $m(G_m \backslash F_m) < \varepsilon/2^k$ and then taking the union of the all the $F_m$, etc

Comment: @PatrickR Yes, you are right.